# Losing links from source to source qualifier while deploying the code from lower env to higher env in informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

While deploying the code from QA to PROD, we're losing links between source and source qualifier in a mapping in Informatica. While the QA still has that link present.

Why do you think it's happening???

Comment: Are you deploying just the mapping, or the complete worktlow?

Answer (score 0):

The source definition in Prod is not in sync with QA.
So, it may happen, while migrating the migration did not consider new definition/coped new definition.
Or while migrating, when it asked to reuse existing definitions, it was ignored.
Or if you are migrating automatically, that `replace related objects` option is not checked.
Or whoever migrating doesnt have proper access to source definition.

Pls make sure you are replacing all related definitions while migrating and be mindful of any error/warnings while migrating.